# Conditional Expectation on Random Variable

Tags: probability

In our lecture notes, $X$ and $Y$ are random variable. From what I understand $E[Y|X]$ is an $F_x$ measurable random variable. In our lecture notes the formula for the conditional expectation was written as:

(1) $E[Y|X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty y \ \ dF_{y|x} \ \ dy$

but I argue that it should be:

(2) $E[Y|X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty y \ \ dF_{y|x} \ \ dx$

because $E[Y|X]=g(X)$ where $g$ is some function of $x$. Or is it (1) because once we integrate over $y$ we are left with a function only dependent on $x$.

Comment: You need to either integrate $y$ against $f_{Y|X}dy$ or $dF_{Y|X}$. You can't mix and match these and have two differentials in a single integral.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using two equivalent arguments to justify two different expressions. In both arguments you correctly affirm that $E[Y \mid X]$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: @A.S. I used to work directly with the PDF in this kind of expressions. Is there any gain in using the CDF? It seems that we are just making the notation more confusing.

Comment: @Carlos pdf might not exist while integration against $dF$ is always well-defined. Integrating against $dF$ also makes $E(g(X))=\int_0^\infty g'(x)(1-F(x))\,dx$ for non-negative $X$ quite obvious - bypassing any need for pdf. But if you allow generalized pdfs (that is view $f(x)$ as a generalized function - for example including a $\delta$ part) then isn't really any difference as then $f\,dx$ is just another way to write $dF$.

Comment: @Carlos To make the above correct: $E(g(X))=g(0)+\int_0^\infty g'(x)\overline F(x)\,dx-\int_{-\infty}^0 g'(x)F(x)\,dx$ for any $X$ where the last term is $0$ for positive $X$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the expectation should be some function $g(x)$. To get this equation, you integrate equation (1) over $y$ to get a function that depends on $x$. In other words,
$$E[Y|X] = g(X) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty y dF_{Y|X}.$$